# How to create a Histogram in python from a histogram source file

Tags: python, histogram, data-analysis

I want to recreate one histogram from two lists in python. I'm new in programming, but I need it for data analysing in my studies. I have some data about measured height values in one list and another list with the assigned counts. E. g. :

```
height = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
count = [294, 420, 410, 2000, 400, 200]
```

How can I create a histogram from these two lists? I'm pretty sure, there must be an easy way to do this, but I haven't figure out yet. The reason I need the histogram in python is because I have to fit a gaussian, which should be no problem, but it's useless without a normalised histogram.
My first intention was to use:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.hist([height, count])
```

but it obviously produced two histograms.

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib's `hist` method expects a list of values. It computes the counts by itself. So one solution would be to generate data that fits your model :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 1. count will be the height of the bars and height the width
height = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
count = [294, 420, 410, 2000, 400, 200]

# 2. create an empty list
#    and add 294 times 0, 420 times 2, and so on...
#    so eventually values will look something like [0, 0, ..., 2, 2, ... 10, 10]
values=[]
for i in range(6): # len(height) or len(count) assuming the two are equal
    values += ([height[i]] * count[i])

plt.figure()
plt.hist(values, bins=range(-1, 12, 2)) # define bin limits
plt.show()
```

This gives you :
[image: Resulting histogram]

Comment: Note that the bars in the histogram don't match the `height` values: the first bar spans x values ranging from 0 to 5/3,  the second bar spans 5/3 to 10/3, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I also thought about (and tried)  creating a list with those repeated values but failed. This was also just an example, I have 2 times 200 data values and can play around with the binning.

Comment: @luuk you were right, I forced the bin limits so this should be better now

Comment: You now only show 5 bins, which are centred between the height values. The correct range would be `range(-1, 12, 2)` (`range(min(height) - binwidth / 2, max(height) + binwidth / 2 + 1, binwidth)`), but a more complicated approach would be required for non-constant bin widths.

Comment: Oh, this is great, that way the labels are centered as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would prefer a bar chart for your dataset.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

height = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
count = [294, 420, 410, 2000, 400, 200]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(height, count, width=1.6)

plt.show()
```

Note that I used the `width` keyword argument in `ax.bar` to set the width of the bars. By default, it is `0.8`, and you could set it to `2` if you want the bars to be connected to each other.

[image: Bar chart]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.If it was nothing but for representation of data I would agree with you, but for gauss fitting I prefer to use the density parameter in the hist function.

Comment: You can simply convert your counts into density values by using the property that the sum of the density values (multiplied by the widths of the bars) is 1. Therefore, you can calculate `density = [val / sum(count) / barwidth for val in count]` manually, where `barwidth = 2` in your case.

Comment: Thank you, this is changing the game. For learning contribution I will try both methods